# Angular - capturar valor do datapicker

Tags: datepicker, angular

Olá, estou com um problema em uma aplicação angular 2, eu tenho 2 Datepicker

```
<input type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="ctrl.campanha.dataInicial" id="datepicker1" ng-init="initDatepicker1()">

<input type="text" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control pull-right" ng-model="ctrl.campanha.dataFinal" id="datepicke2" ng-init="initDatepicker2()">
```

estou inicializando eles no meu *Controller* por meio dos seguintes metodos

```
$scope.initDatepicker1 = function () {

            $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
                autoclose: true
            })
        }

        $scope.initDatepicker2 = function () {
            $('#datepicke2').datepicker({
                autoclose: true
            })
        }
function validacoes() {


        console.log(vm.campanha.dataInicial)
        console.log(vm.campanha.dataFinal)
        return true
    }
```

Quando tento recuperar os valores dos *Datepicker* por meio da função `validacoes()`, que e chamada por meio de um *ng-click* eles aparecem como *undefined*, apesar de aparecerem  dentro do *input* os valores, veja: 
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: tente `console.log($scope.ctrl.campanha.dataInicial);` e `console.log($scope.ctrl.campanha.dataFinal);`

Comment: acabei de tentar... resultado:  "undefined"

Comment: Bom dia Matheus, o código apresentado por você é Angular 1, aconselho a melhorar sua descrição para que outros pessoas possam te ajudar.